# What is the unit in which value returned by OL3's geom.getArea() method?

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers, maps

1. If It is Going to return in some standard unit What is it ? so that i can convert to my desired unit.
2. Is it possible to set the Measuring Unit type like ESRI's API support?, That    i'm able to set in terms of Sq meter, Meter, Sq Miles, Miles, Sq Km... etc
3. If there is no such standard unit going to be returned, how do i can convert it to Miles, KM, Feet etc..

Answer (score 2):

The area will be in the units of your map projection.
Default is EPSG:3857 -> meters

```
map.getView().getProjection()
```

will get your the information